# Error while starting android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am getting this error while starting android studio. Can you please help

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6b09ea7208, pid=4501, tid=0x00007f6a7aafc700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 6230 C1 org.iq80.snappy.UnsafeMemory.copyLong([BI[BI)V (116 bytes) @ 0x00007f6b09ea7208 [0x00007f6b09ea71a0+0x68]
```

Comment: I see you sit on Linux. What is your distro?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 @Shaq